# Aparecer texto ao digitar na textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Considerem o seguinte exemplo:

Tenho uma *textarea* que, quando o usuário digitar algo nela, um pequeno texto logo abaixo deve ser exibido, e em determinado tempo após o usuário terminar de digitar sua frase, o texto deve desaparecer!

Eu até consegui algo aqui, vejam: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wagner/UsBGy/embedded/result)

Porém ao digitar o texto tem um pequeno efeito que eu não gosto! O texto fica meio que 'aparecendo e sumindo' muito rápido, eu quero que simplesmente ao digitar o texto apareça e ao parar ele suma, com um *delay* nesse meio tempo.

Comment: Aviso: essa questão virou um Code Golf de jQuery. Quem se dispõe a resolver o problema sem usar jQuery!? *(Dica: CSS3)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coloque um `.stop(true)` antes das animações: ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uSSpA/))

```
$('#myTextarea').on('keyup',function(){
  $('#showedText').text('Just a test!')
    .stop(true).fadeIn().delay(700).fadeOut();
});
```

O [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) para as animações executadas, usando `true` como argumento também irá limpar a fila de animações, evitando que animações antigas sejam executadas.

Answer (score 5):

<sub>*Eu me disponho! E já que é completamente diferente da primeira abro como outra resposta:*</sub>

Você não precisa usar jQuery: use CSS3 e, caso precisar, [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) ou seu equivalente em jQuery:

**Mostrar texto enquanto a textarea tiver foco** não precisa de JS: ([jsbin](http://jsbin.com/gigayiho/1/edit))

```
#showedText {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s 1s;
}
#myTextarea:focus + #showedText {
  opacity: 1; transition-delay: 0;
}
```

**Mostrar texto enquanto a textarea estiver sendo editada** usa pouco JS: ([jsbin](http://jsbin.com/gigayiho/3/edit))

```
#showedText {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s 1s;
}
#showedText.editing {
  opacity: 1; transition-delay: 0;
}
```

*JavaScript utilizado - Vanilla JS:*

```
var myTextarea = document.getElementById('myTextarea');
var showedText = document.getElementById('showedText');
myTextarea.addEventListener('keydown', function () {
  showedText.className += ' editing ';
  setTimeout(function () {
    showedText.className = showedText.className
      .replace(/(^|\b)editing(\b|$)/g, '');
  }, 500);
});
```

*JavaScript utilizado - jQuery ou Zepto:*

```
var showedText = $('#showedText');
$('#myTextarea').on('keydown', function () {
  showedText.addClass('editing');
  setTimeout(function () {
    showedText.removeClass('editing');
  }, 500);
});
```

*Edição:* enquanto eu escrevia essa parede de código outras pessoas se aventuraram em usar CSS3, logo deixo uma dica ao autor: [use prefixfree](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/).

Comment: Boa demais a resposta apenas usando CSS3 ;) +1

Answer (score 4):

Função que pode ser reutilizada em `n` outros textareas:

```
function mostratexto(el, txt, ms){
    var t;
    el.on('keyup',function(){
        clearTimeout(t);
        txt.fadeIn('slow');
        t = setTimeout(function(){
            txt.fadeOut('slow');
        }, ms);
    });
}
```

Basicamente o que a função vai fazer é disparar um `timeout` e remover o `timeout` antigo a cada vez que uma tecla for pressionada com o `textarea` em foco, ou seja, ela reinicia o contador que vai sumir com o texto, previnindo o texto de ficar "piscando".

Exemplo: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/K2f8E/1/)

Answer (score 2):

O html:

```
 <textarea onkeyup="stop()" onkeydown="start()">
 </textarea>
 <span id="span" style="opacity: 0">digitando...</span>
```

o javascript:

```
 function start(){
   var span = document.getElementById('span');
   span.style.opacity = "1";
   span.style.webkitTransition = "0.1s"
 }
 function stop(){
   var span = document.getElementById('span');
   span.style.opacity = "0";    
   span.style.webkitTransition = "1.5s"
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Além de usar um `.stop()` eu inseri o `setTimeOut()` para controlar o "desaparecer" do texto

```
$(function(){
    $('#myTextarea').on('keyup',function(){
        $('#showedText').text('Just a test!').stop().fadeIn(700, "linear");
    setTimeout(function(){$('#showedText').stop().fadeOut(700, "linear");},2000);
    });
});
```

Você pode ver o código funcionando [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/UsBGy/1/)